# Efficient cutting of mesh edges

Tags: reference-request, mesh

I am looking for efficient algorithms to cut a mesh along edges. I have a (half-edge) mesh and a list of inner edges that I want to cut, such that both are new boundary edges. At each vertex there can be an arbitrary number of cuts, either starting at the vertex or crossing the vertex. If you are cutting incrementally, you can also assume that each cut starts at the vertex. I do not want to cut the mesh into several connected components, but only to splice it along a chain of edges, which often will not result in a new connected component.

In my current approach I mark each vertex that belongs to one or more cut edges and then iterate over the adjacent edges and if they are marked as a cut edge I add the edge and the triangles seen before the edge to a list. Then I create a new vertex for each entry in the list, remove the triangles that belong to the entry (i.e. the triangles seen between the cut edge and the previous cut edge) and re-insert them using the new vertex.

I think this approach may be quite inefficient, but I haven't found much literature on how to cut meshes, as most papers that turn up when looking for algorithms explain how to find a good cut, but not how to actually cut a mesh along these edges.

Splitting a mesh into connected components when the cut edges connect two boundary vertices is also rather simple, as you can do a search from a seed and add neighbouring triangles if the edge between the triangles is not a cut edge, and then rebuild the mesh by copying the vertex set and adding only the triangles of the connected component found. However, this algorithm does not work if you want to add cuts that do not create a new connected component.

Are there any known algorithms for splitting mesh edges in an efficient way, i.e., splitting an inner edge into two boundary edges? If it is difficult with a half-edge data structure, I would also consider using other data structures that are more efficient for such operations.

Comment: Since you have a solution, why are you looking for different solutions? You say "I think this approach may be quite inefficient", but have you actually measured this? There is no need to replace a working algorithm if it is not a bottleneck.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I want to generate a lot of different cuts and updating large meshes can become a bottleneck. I am not sure if it is one yet, but I put it here as `reference-request` because my impression is that this must be a topic for which papers exist how to optimize it, compare data structures and so on and I am interested in what research may exist which I didn't find yet because the topic is dominated by algorithms for finding inconspicuous seams.